# Find penultimate instance of specific character in NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have an `NSString` of pipe-separated values, like this:

`|123|456|789|abc|def|ghi|jkl|`

I’d like to find the position of the second-to-last pipe. I know that I can use something like this to find the last one:

`[ms rangeOfString:@"|" options:NSBackwardsSearch]`

But, I’d like to find the second-to-last one, since I’m going to trim the `jkl|` part.

What would be a clean way of going about this?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but maybe you could use `componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"` to extract the values?

Comment: NSString *sampleStr = @"|123|456|789|abc|def|ghi|jkl|"          [sampleStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]; you will get all strings then you easely find one you want

Comment: That could be rather expensive if the string is very long. And it doesn't give the position of the second-to-last pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the last one, then find the one in front of it by using a range.